# Pricing sanity check

Tags: cartthrob

[image: Pricing options]

We have two pricing options:

1. Pay as you go ($30 one off)
2. Per term/semester ($25 a week, paid in full for the semester with each class varying in price and length)

What is the best way to do this type of pricing in CartThrob where we can enter in the amount of lessons per semester (preferably in the cartThrob fields) and the two rates (pay as you go + per class per semester) and it automatically spits out the per semester cost?

[image: sdf]

Thank you!